# Why should the supremum of lower function be lesser than or equal to maximum of upper function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

$$\int_a^b s(x) dx \leq \sup S \leq \inf T \leq \int_a^b t(x) dx$$

[Screenshot from Tom.M.Apostol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27UbY.png)

In pg 74 of 2nd ed in Tom.M.Apostol Calculus, he introduces integration as a summation of approximation of areas of infinite step functions, between upper $t(x)$ step function and lower step function $s(x)$ $(s(x) \leq f(x) \leq t(x))$. Then he goes on a proof on how $f(x)$ is unique with the above mentioned step. For an arbitrary function, as is the case, isn't there a possibility of infinum of $t$ being lesser than supremum of $s$?

infinum of s is kind of minimum value in the given domain for s, and supremum is maximum value

The reason I have trouble believing it, is this scenario:

[My imagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jawER.png)

In the local domain [0,x3], supremum of S is s(x3), infinum of T is t(x1), but s(x3)>t(x1). Isn't it contradictory? Excuse me for any error in trying to convey it

Comment: What is the difference between $s$ and $S$, $t$ and $T$? Are there any constraints for $a$ and $b$?

Comment: S is the set of s(x) and T is the set of t(x), where s(x) and t(x) are ordinates that define upper and lower approximation of area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that $S$ is the set of integrals of step functions that are bounded above by $f$ on $[a, b]$, and $T$ is the set of integrals of step functions bounded below by $f$. Then, note that

$$s(x) \leq f(x) \leq t(x) \ \text{for any $x \in [a, b]$} \implies \int_{a}^{b} s(x) \ \mathrm{d}x \leq \int_{a}^{b} t(x) \ \mathrm{d}x.$$

We can obtain the inequality above by considering a refinement of the partitions defining $s$ and $t$. Therefore, if $u \in S$ and $v \in T$, then $u \leq v$ necessarily. Then by taking the supremum over $u \in S$, for any fixed $v \in T$, we have that $\sup S \leq v$. Finally, taking the infimum over all $v \in T$, we get that $\sup S \leq \inf T$.

Comment: Therefore, if u∈S and v∈T, then u≤v necessarily.                                                                        Why should u≤v? For example, in a exponential or quadratic function, There are some v∈T for u∈S such that v≤u, especially when t(x1)≤s(x2) for x2>x1

Comment: $S$ and $T$ represent upper and lower sums for using step functions, not the function values of $f$ itself.